# AWS CloudWatch agent shows "cwoc_status": "stopped"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have installed AWS CloudWatch agent on my EC2 instance and configured with the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard`. The AWS credentials are stored in `.aws/credentials` and picked up by the wizard during configuration.

Now I am checking the status of the agent, but I do not understand what `"cwoc_status": "stopped"` refers to?

Here the output of the agent status:

```
ubuntu@ip-address:~$ sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2021-02-09T05:37:12+00:00",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "stopped",
  "cwoc_starttime": "",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.247347.3b250378"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally discovered that `cwoc` refers to [AWS-OpenTelemetry Collector](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/monitoring-application-health-and-performance-with-aws-distro-for-opentelemetry/), which I think has been installed by default by `amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb` that I used to install the CWAgent on my EC2.
I found it by doing the following grep

```
ubuntu@ip-address:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent$ grep -r cwoc
```

which found the string in the file `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl` where I found that reference to the folder `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/cwagent-otel-collector`.

Googling `otel-collector` I found the OpenTelemetry Collector.

Comment: But does it need to be running for the metrics to be picked up? I get a similar status and I'm not seeing my metrics in cloudwatch.

Comment: The metrics sent by the running Cloudwatch agent are picked up. If you want to send the OpenTelemetry metrics, I guess you need to start it too.

Answer (score 1):

cwoc is for open telemetry for use by tools like NewRelic and others.
But many of those tools now will read from Cloudwatch to avoid the hassle of configuring every server.